# Jcrop .. duvida para salvar imagem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jcrop

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, e nele o usuário pode fazer um corte de uma imagem (que fiz com o jcrop) porém depois que o usuário recorta ela, ela aparece na tela. 
O que eu gostaria era que logo após dele recortar, eu poder pegar ela e salvar na pasta de *uploads* e salvar o link dela no bd (isso é o de menos o link), porém não entendo muito de utilizar imagens com o php e não sei quais dessas informações que o jcrop retorna que eu devo utilizar para salvar a imagem. Seguem prints:

Aqui é apenas o form HTML:

[image: Aqui é apenas o form HTML]
o php que  retorna  a imagem recortada
[image: o php que retorna a imagem recortada]
A imagem recortada que ele me retorna
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O amigo, você pode colocar a seguinte coisa:

```
$valid_ext = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['img']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (in_array($ext, $valid_ext)) {
        $path = 'uploads/'. uniqid() . "." . $ext;
        echo "<img src='path' />";
    } else {
        echo 'Problema na extensao'; 
    }
} else {
    echo 'requisicao ruim';
}
```